Camera is unable to capture whole model in Model target vufforia in Unity
I am making an application for model target in vufforia I have tested it by scanning 3d model in 3d viewer and it is working fine . For this i am using device - surface pro 9 . But the issue is when i am scanning actual model through camera , Whole model is not covered in Camera frame because of that model size is too big and room size is less i have gone end corner to have it on camera frame . But Camera can't covered whole model in frame .
I have tried with to go on end corner but camera cant covered whole model in Camera frame then what i can do

you might want to adjust the guide view when you generate the target or at runtime https://developer.vuforia.com/library/model-targets/model-target-guide-view

It should be fine to only have a partly scanned object as a Model Target.
Look at it this way. If the AR experience is in the same small room, then there's no way for the user to move behind the object.
As mentioned by others, it's more important to get the Guide View at the correct position to start tracking the object.
If you're using Advanced Views, select the Observation preset or Constrained User Positions and Target Extent. These views are better at detecting the object up close. See Advanced Views for the details.
